# Lookup Alternative/Filtering services in SSRS

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, reporting-services, rdlc

I would like to discuss about filtering services in SSRS. I am new to it and there are alot of things I am not sure. I have searched other alternate usage of lookup function. Is there any other possible way rather than using cascading parameters? Or, any other way? The data have to be generated dynamically by another dataset.

This is what I want to achieve:
I want to dynamically change the data value for Qualification (a textbox which is in the page header) according to the data value in Hidden Column.I am using lookup function now. But when I converted to rdlc and deploy it is giving me aggregate error.

[image]

Qualification and Student are in two different scope as I separated with red line.

Thanks.

Comment: Subreports might give you the functionality that you're looking for .It's a pretty broad subject and there are plenty of tutorials and documentation te be found. I'm certain you should be able to achieve this on your own with a little effort. If you're having problems you can always come back and ask specific question to get more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,I have solved the issue using "ReportItems.value"
I tried to create hidden column/textbox (textbox-B) in my pagebody. And another textbox,(call it textbox-A) in header. Then, referenced back from textbox-B,inside textbox-A, by using ReportItems expression. Clear example is on:

> https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2972/sql-server-reporting-services-reportitems-collection/

Thanks.